# QGIS Modeller- Field Calculator on intermediate step fails to find field

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler

As part of my model I union a bunch of PostGIS layers (views), each containing the same 'feature' field (char(64)). After the union, there are a numerous feature_2, feature_3 etc etc fields in the output.
Example View:
[image: Example View]
Model
[image: Model]
I want to store these values into the original 'feature' field but the field calculator does not recognise the fields?

Field Calculator- Pre Calculated Value

```
CASE
WHEN "feature_2" IS NOT NULL THEN '1'
WHEN "feature_3" IS NOT NULL THEN '2'
WHEN "feature_4" IS NOT NULL THEN '3'
WHEN "feature_5" IS NOT NULL THEN '4'
WHEN "feature_6" IS NOT NULL THEN '5'
WHEN "feature_7" IS NOT NULL THEN '6'
END
```

Result

> feature setback calc: Field 'feature_2' not found
> Example output of the union:
> [image: Example union output]

Creating a temporary output from the model from the same step that the field calculator uses shows that these fields DO exist?
What's going on here?

Comment: Can you provide some practical example of your views & union result. Why isn't the union query defined to report 'feature' of each view, in the resulting 'feature' column if that's your need?

Comment: Can you provide the model? Otherwise, we have to speculalte what you're doing.

Comment: @Kasper- Updated to include some pictures. Re the field calculator, I do actually want to update the existing 'feature' column with the value of the 'feature_x' column if it isn't null. The example above was me just reverting to try and get something in that column/debugging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to this problem was not to use a CASE but to use a COALESCE into the final field (planting_class) which will use the temporary field names (planting_class_1 2 3 etc):

```
coalesce("planting_class_2",
"planting_class_3",
"planting_class_4",
"planting_class_5",
"planting_class_6",
"planting_class_7",
"planting_class_8",
"planting_class_9", 
"planting_class")
```